# Complex Manifold question

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology, topological-vector-spaces, complete-spaces, complex-manifolds

So let's take the following:

> $$C\subset \mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{C})$$ where
> $$C = \left\{[x_0:x_1:x_2]; x_0^2 + x_1^2 + x_2^2 = 0 \right\}$$

How can I proceed to prove that $C$ is a complex manifold?
($\mathbb{P}$ denotes the Projective Space).

Comment: You can use the (holomorphic) implicit function theorem. Then all you need to verify is that the defining equation has nonzero differential everywhere.

Comment: @D.Brogan Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I could have answered my own question, instead of deleting it, for it can help someone in the future. Hope it's all right.

In $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{C})$ we want $Z(x_0^2 + x_1^2 + x_2^2)$ to be holomorphic. ($Z(\cdot)$ denotes the place of the zeroes of $\cdot$).

We then have $Z(1 + x^2 + y^2)$ where
$$x = \dfrac{x_1}{x_0} ~~~~~~~ y = \dfrac{x_2}{x_0}$$

The Jacobian $J(1+x^2+y^2)$ has the maximum rank out from $(0, 0)$ but $(0, 0) \notin Z(1+x^2 +y^2)$.

Whence $C$ is a complex manifold according to the implicit holomorphic function theorem.